# Make variable hold htmlcollection

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a vb.net program to parse an HTML doc that is in a webbrowser control. Basically, I need to find the specified table (by class) and then go row by row checking the 5 and 6th columns against certain criteria.

```
Dim eles As HtmlElementCollection 'Stores contents of html document

eles = iexplore.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")

'Get table with tasks
For Each he As HtmlElement In eles
    MsgBox(Len(he.Children))
    If he.GetAttribute("class") = tclass Then
        'what to do when we have the table

    End If
Next
```

The problem is that it's throwing an exception: Object reference not set to instance of an object

I thought that's what I was doing by assigning an htmlcollection to eles with the line:

```
eles = iexplore.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")
```

If this is wrong, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think you already post this question some minutes before?? Anyway, try keeping a watch on your `iexplore.Document`, which according to me is null

Comment: Where do you get the exception, i mean at which line? Use the debugger, set a breakpoint at `Dim eles As HtmlElementCollection` and look what happens if you forward. You can even inspect values of all variables in the quick-watch-window. That should help to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eles = iexplore.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")` is NOT wrong, just that your `iexplore` or `iexplore.Document` has not been instantiated.

That's why you're having the exception ***"Object reference not set to instance of an object"***.

You can't read the elements of an object which is null or nothing.

Comment: iexplore is the name of a webbrowser control and the code comes after a loop while iexplore.isbusy to make sure the page is loaded before retrieving a document

Comment: Yeah but iexplore will have a value only if you Navigate to a link, else, it won't be instantiated

Comment: Yea, I forgot to put that into the question but I was navigating to a url. The problem was that the URL was prompting for username / pw but the isbusy method wasn't considering this as being busy. I fixed the problem by navigating to a random URL that requires a logon in the load event.  Once that PW is entered, they never have to enter it again and the pages load fine. Yay for security! -.-